# Vizualisation about line search in Linear Programming?

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming, visualization

I am trying to visualize this recursive algorithm in LP, Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search). I am looking for references about in which kind of problems is this used and what does it really look like?

I am also interested about visual comparisons between other basic LP algorithms.

Comment: Line search is a technique usually used in unconstrained nonlinear optimization. You can apply it to linear programming only after somehow converting your LP into an unconstrained problem, e.g. by using barrier functions.

Answer (score 1):

About points 15-20 in the lecture [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTCtkkqrY8A) by Stanford. I cannot fully yet understand it but as reference.

[image]

A key decision in line search seems to be a step-size. And please notice that there are many different kinds of line searches.

**Related**

- The page 463 [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) i.e. the chapter 9.2 Descent Methods.